# rails -v cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

Ubuntu 14.04.

So everything was working fine and I had my terminal open with two tabs - one tab had webbrick running on my sebcoles project, and the other tab I used to clone my english_teacher repo. It all downloaded fine and I changed into the directory.

I'll just paste everything here - it's all pretty clear:

```
andrew:projects$ cd pinteresting
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/andrew/projects/pinteresting/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

ruby-2.1.5 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.1.5'

andrew:pinteresting$ rvm install ruby-2.1.5

Warning, new version of rvm available '1.26.11', you are using older version '1.26.10'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.1.5.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.1.5 - #configure
ruby-2.1.5 - #download
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 23.1M  100 23.1M    0     0  1189k      0  0:00:19  0:00:19 --:--:-- 1381k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.1.5 - #validate archive
ruby-2.1.5 - #extract
ruby-2.1.5 - #validate binary
ruby-2.1.5 - #setup
ruby-2.1.5 - #gemset created /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global
ruby-2.1.5 - #importing gemset /home/andrew/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems....................................
ruby-2.1.5 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.1.5 - #gemset created /home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
ruby-2.1.5 - #importing gemsetfile /home/andrew/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.1.5 - #generating default wrappers........

andrew:pinteresting$ heroku status

=== Heroku Status
Development: No known issues at this time.
Production:  No known issues at this time.

andrew:pinteresting$ rails s

/home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/rails:7:in `<main>'

andrew:pinteresting$ rails -v

/home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/rails:7:in `<main>'
```

So, basically I'm screwed at the moment - I can't do anything. Help!

Comment: I should add that everything still works fine in the first tab, but now I have to shut down my laptop. I expect that when I reboot this won't be the case anymore :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just had to run 
    bundle install 
and everything was fine. However, for my pinteresting repo, which uses the paperclip gem, I had to run 
    sudo apt-get install imagemagick
in order to upload images in development.

Haven't dared commit anything new and push and deploy to heroku yet though. I think it should be fine though (touch wood).

Answer (score 10):

You have installed `rvm` but forget to install `rails` gem. Install it use:

```
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case, following command works.

1. remove Gemfile.lock
2. `bundle install`
3. `bundle clean --force`

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same error. I forgot to switch to correct ruby version and correct gemset using rvm. That's it, I was able to sort this issue.

```
$rvm list
$rvm use ruby version 
$rvm gemset use gemset-name
```