# Rails troubleshooting: rails/cli (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I'm currently trying to learn Ruby on Rails using the ebook/tutorial by Michael Hartl (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/), and everything was running fine until section 2.3 on generating the scaffold for Microposts.

Executing

> $ rails generate scaffold Micropost content:text user_id:integer

Resulted in the following error:

> c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -
>   - rails/cli (LoadError)
>           from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in`
>   require'
>        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
>        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rails:23:in`load'
>        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rails:23:in `'

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling rails and railties, gem clean, and a complete reinstall of Ruby 2.0, but the problem still persists. (Reinstalling rails got the rails -v command working again but starting up rails server or rails generate kicked back the error again). Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Edit to add:

If it helps, my Gemfile also looks like

> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> gem 'rails', '4.2.2' gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.2' gem 'uglifier', '2.5.3'
>   gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0' gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3' gem
>   'turbolinks', '2.3.0' gem 'jbuilder', '2.2.3' gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0',
>   group: :doc
>
> group :development, :test do   gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.9'   gem 'byebug',
>   '3.4.0'   gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'   gem 'spring', '1.1.3' 
>   end    group :production do   gem 'pg', '0.17.1'   gem
>   'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'  end

Comment: did you see this SO post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083446/rails-v-cannot-load-such-file-rails-cli-loaderror, It suggests running a bundle install.

Comment: Yes I've tried bundle install

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452652/ruby-on-rails-error-making-new-app-rb55in-require

Comment: Running rails -v after rails install and bundle install is giving me:
bin/rails:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands (LoadError)
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Answer (score 3):

I get that message when Rails is not installed at the system level.  Since you're using bundler, execute the rails command in the context of the bundle using:

`bundle exec rails generate scaffold Micropost content:text user_id:integer`