# rails new my app failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I followed the steps on installing ruby on https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10

I tried the command rails new app

but I keep on getting this error Help!!

/home/paulydee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
    from /home/paulydee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083446/rails-v-cannot-load-such-file-rails-cli-loaderror)? If so, install rails by calling `gem install rails`

Comment: Didnt solve my problem. Do you have any good online links that can assist me with a proper installation